# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. IN SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, ssis

I have a SSIS package that contains the Script task.

Inside the Script task we are calling GetConnectionForSchema() method to create OLEDB Connection.

In my local machine SSIS package is working fine but when I deploy the package to the server then it is throwing an exception "**Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object**"

We don't have SSDT installed on server so not able to debug the package there.

Comment: I am getting the error when I run the package through Integration service catalogs but it is working fine in my local system.

Answer (score 0):

You could try few different things :

1. Your database connection within the script task is not accessible from the server, so you would need to add an absolute path to it.
2. You could try connecting to the OLE DB Database via another task with the absolute path within your package and than once you have access to the data pass it to the Script Transformation Task.
3. If you could just use other tasks within SSIS without using Script Task and access the database on the server, than you will need to debug your code.

Based on the information you provided this is what I can say at the moment.